# Creating a new column based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with ID, START and END time stamp and another reference table with ID, TIME and WEIGHT columns. Now, I am trying to assign the weights to the df1 based on times.

If the time of df2 is in between start and end of df1 the corresponding weight should be assigned for the record in df1. I can simply use a left join but the problem is there might be two or 3 weights assigned for the same ID

df1:

```
 ID             START              END
2591642409  2018-08-20 06:00:00 2018-08-20 16:59:59
2591642409  2018-08-20 17:00:00 2018-08-21 01:59:59
2591642409  2018-08-21 02:00:00 2018-08-21 14:59:59
2591642409  2018-08-21 15:00:00 2018-08-21 15:59:59
2591642409  2018-08-21 15:00:00 2018-08-21 15:59:59
2591642409  2018-08-21 15:00:00 2018-08-21 14:59:59
2591642409  2018-08-21 15:00:00 2018-08-21 14:59:59
2591642409  2018-08-21 16:00:00 2018-08-25 11:59:59
2626784515  2018-09-12 12:41:00 2018-09-12 17:59:59
2626784515  2018-09-12 18:00:00 2018-09-12 22:27:59
2626784515  2018-09-12 22:28:00 2018-09-13 23:32:59
2626784515  2018-09-14 00:00:00 2018-09-13 23:59:59
2631776057  2018-09-16 03:29:00 2018-09-16 12:39:59
2631776057  2018-09-16 12:40:00 2018-09-16 13:33:59
2631776057  2018-09-16 13:34:00 2018-09-16 14:10:59
2694817807  2018-10-31 10:30:00 2018-11-01 15:57:59
2694817807  2018-11-01 15:58:00 2018-11-02 22:59:59
2694817807  2018-11-02 23:00:00 2018-11-02 23:55:59
2694817807  2018-11-02 23:56:00 2018-11-09 00:18:59
2694817807  2018-11-09 00:19:00 2018-11-09 05:55:59
2694817807  2018-11-09 05:56:00 2018-11-09 08:34:59
2694817807  2018-11-09 08:35:00 2018-11-09 16:59:59
2694817807  2018-11-09 17:00:00 2018-11-10 04:29:59
2694817807  2018-11-10 04:30:00 2018-11-10 09:23:59
2694817807  2018-11-10 09:24:00 2018-11-11 03:09:59
2694817807  2018-11-11 03:10:00 2018-11-11 16:54:59
2694817807  2018-11-11 16:55:00 2018-11-11 20:55:59
2694817807  2018-11-11 20:56:00 2018-11-12 19:59:59
2711413129  2018-11-12 20:00:00 2018-11-13 04:20:59
```

df2:

```
     ID          TIME               WEIGHT
2591642409  2018-08-15 01:42:13      3.38
2626784515  2018-09-12 14:56:03      3.7
2631776057  2018-09-16 07:05:45      3.7
2694817807  2018-10-31 14:21:54      4.5
2694817807  2018-11-09 05:29:52      4.8
2711413129  2018-11-12 17:14:26      4.8
```

Expected df:

```
 ID             START              END                  WEIGHT
2591642409  2018-08-20 06:00:00 2018-08-20 16:59:59     3.38
2591642409  2018-08-20 17:00:00 2018-08-21 01:59:59     3.38
2591642409  2018-08-21 02:00:00 2018-08-21 14:59:59     3.38
2591642409  2018-08-21 15:00:00 2018-08-21 15:59:59     3.38
2591642409  2018-08-21 15:00:00 2018-08-21 15:59:59     3.38
2591642409  2018-08-21 15:00:00 2018-08-21 14:59:59     3.38 
2591642409  2018-08-21 15:00:00 2018-08-21 14:59:59     3.38
2591642409  2018-08-21 16:00:00 2018-08-25 11:59:59     3.38
2626784515  2018-09-12 12:41:00 2018-09-12 17:59:59     3.7
2626784515  2018-09-12 18:00:00 2018-09-12 22:27:59     3.7
2626784515  2018-09-12 22:28:00 2018-09-13 23:32:59     3.7
2626784515  2018-09-14 00:00:00 2018-09-13 23:59:59     3.7
2631776057  2018-09-16 03:29:00 2018-09-16 12:39:59     3.7 
2631776057  2018-09-16 12:40:00 2018-09-16 13:33:59     3.7
2631776057  2018-09-16 13:34:00 2018-09-16 14:10:59     3.7
2694817807  2018-10-31 10:30:00 2018-11-01 15:57:59     4.5
2694817807  2018-11-01 15:58:00 2018-11-02 22:59:59     4.5
2694817807  2018-11-02 23:00:00 2018-11-02 23:55:59     4.5
2694817807  2018-11-02 23:56:00 2018-11-09 00:18:59     4.5
2694817807  2018-11-09 00:19:00 2018-11-09 05:55:59     4.5
2694817807  2018-11-09 05:56:00 2018-11-09 08:34:59     4.8
2694817807  2018-11-09 08:35:00 2018-11-09 16:59:59     4.8
2694817807  2018-11-09 17:00:00 2018-11-10 04:29:59     4.8
2694817807  2018-11-10 04:30:00 2018-11-10 09:23:59     4.8
2694817807  2018-11-10 09:24:00 2018-11-11 03:09:59     4.8
2694817807  2018-11-11 03:10:00 2018-11-11 16:54:59     4.8
2694817807  2018-11-11 16:55:00 2018-11-11 20:55:59     4.8
2694817807  2018-11-11 20:56:00 2018-11-12 19:59:59     4.8
2711413129  2018-11-12 20:00:00 2018-11-13 04:20:59     4.8
```

I am using the following code

```
mask = (df2['TIME'] > df1['START']) & (df2['TIME'] < df1['END'])
df1['WEIGHTS'] = np.where(mask, df2['WEIGHTS'], '')
```

but it throws a value error saying

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

I'd really appreciate if I can get some help.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the `TIME` is not in the interval defined by `START` and `END`? Based on your expected df it seems you want a match even then.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare two series with different name from different dataframe in pandas. You have to either change the name or join the two dataframe. In this case, I believe join is the best choice. Since `len(df1) != len(df2)` After join the dataframe, you should able to use the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try first joining or merging the two frames first... then apply your filter

```
df1.set_index('ID', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('ID', inplace=True)
df = df1.join(df2)

df_filtered = df[(df['TIME'] > df['START']) & (df['TIME'] < df['END'])]
```